# MySQL: Foreign Key is always 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create two tables in MySQL and link them together via a user-id (uid) and a post-id (pid). The users table has an auto incrementing primary key uid and the posts table has a primary key pid. The foreign key for the posts table is the uid of the posts table. For some reason the uid column of the posts table is always 0 when it should instead point to the uid value of the users table.

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    uid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    dob varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);

  CREATE TABLE posts
(
    pid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    uid int NOT NULL,
    username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    date date NOT NULL,
    title varchar(225) NOT NULL,
    content mediumtext NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(pid),
    FOREIGN KEY(uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
);
```

The output of the two tables is:

```
    mysql> select *from users;
+-----+----------------+-------------+------------+----------+
| uid | email          | username    | dob        | password |
+-----+----------------+-------------+------------+----------+
|   1 | test@test.com  | Test User1  | 11/11/1111 | passwor1 |
|   2 | test2@test.com | Test User2  | 22/22/2222 | passwor2 |
|   3 | test3@test.com | Test User 3 | 33/33/3333 | passwor3 |
+-----+----------------+-------------+------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *from posts;
+-----+-----+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| pid | uid | username    | date       | title          | content                                          |
+-----+-----+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|   1 |   0 | Test User 3 | 2014-08-08 | Test Post      | TEST
|   2 |   0 | Test User 3 | 2014-08-08 | Test Post 2    | Test post please ignore  
|   3 |   0 | Test User 3 | 2014-08-08 | TEST AGAIn     | Test test test test test
+-----+-----+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From the data above the uid column should be '3' which is the uid for Test User 3 defined in the users table. Instead the uid column is always 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the insert statement you are using to populate the tables with these lines?

Comment: A foreign key value is not magically filled in, but has to be entered in the `INSERT` statement. It's meant for ensuring referential integrity. I.e. you cannot generate an order for a non-existing customer. You should look into the `INSERT` script, or provide that script here as well.

Comment: Are you actually inserting the uid value into posts when you create a new post record? That doesn't happen magically just because you have created a foreign key.

Comment: You are in a confusion that uid in post table will automatically filled in because you have created a FK on it. NO, you will have to insert the data accordingly. there is no automatic business here.

Comment: Yes thats it. I guess I completely misunderstood how foreign keys actually function. Ill rework my insert statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INSERT statement must contain your foreign key.

If the post had a relation back to user 1, your insert statement would look like:

```
INSERT INTO posts (uid, username, date, title, content) VALUES(1,'test','2014-08-01','title','content');
```